# asp.net url concealment?

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net 2005 app, I would like conceal the app structure from the user.  Currently, the end user can learn intimate details of my web app as they navigate and watch the url change.  I don't want the end user to know about my application structure.  I would like the browser url to not change if possible.    Please advise.

thanks

E.A.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by "intimate details"?

Answer (score 3):

URL rewriting is the only one that can provide any kind of real concealment.

Just moving the requests to AJAX or to frames, means anyone (well, more advanced users) can still see those requests being fired, just not in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to use frames - a single frame that holds your application and is 100% * 100%. The URL will not change though the underlying URL can still be seen via "View Frame info", however only advanced users will even figure that out.

In your pages, make sure that they are contained inside the holding frame.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities.

1) use AJAX to power everything. This will mean that the user never leaves the home page

2) use postbacks to power everything. In this, you'd have all those pages be user controls which you progrmattically hide or show.

3) URL rewriting (especially if this is asp.net 3.0 or later)

Answer (score 1):

My site uses url parameters to dynamically load ascx files into a single main aspx. So if I get 'page_id=123' on the query string, I load the corresponding ascx. The url changes, but only the query string - the domain part remains the same.

If you want the url to remain precisely the same at all times, then frames (per Oded) or ajax (per Stephen) are probably the only ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use URL encryption

A simple & straight article: http://devcity.net/PrintArticle.aspx?ArticleID=47

and another article: https://web.archive.org/web/20210610035204/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/083105-1.aspx

HTH